# How to acquire clipboard history in Windows 10 (October Update)?

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to use the Clipboard History feature that comes with Windows Update in my C# application but I couldn't find any article about it.

I checked [Clipboard Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=netframework-4.7.2) but found nothing about it.

Comment: Welcome to the new Microsoft where they don't believe in exposing new Windows features via public APIs much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Clipboard history is not exposed in the Windows API. The [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard) Windows Runtime type, on the other hand, does provide the [GetHistoryItemsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.gethistoryitemsasync#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard_GetHistoryItemsAsync) member, as well as a [HistoryChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.historychanged) event.

As a type with the [DualApiPartitionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute) it can be used from UWP applications as well as classic desktop applications.